# "it was printed using..."

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

Hi I couldn't figure out the usage "it was printed using the new steam presses..."

> [Herschel’s Preliminary Discourse was a product of the industrial age: **it was printed using the new steam presses**, on cheap paper, with
> mechanised stereotyping instead of hand-set blocks, and it was bound
> not in leather but in calico cloth and cardboard.](https://www.lrb.co.uk/the-paper/v36/n22/mike-jay/like-cooking-a-dumpling)

It seems ungrammatical that "using" follows "was printed". Is "using" here an adjective? What is the reduced form here?

Comment: The steam presses were used to print the book - it's as simple as that.

Comment: "using the new steam presses" is a [participial phrase](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar/sentences/participial-phrases.html).

Answer (score 1):

I paste here the whole paragraph.

> Herschel’s Preliminary Discourse was a product of the industrial age: it was printed using the new steam presses, on cheap paper, with mechanised stereotyping instead of hand-set blocks, and it was bound not in leather but in calico cloth and cardboard.

*printed* is a verb.  Why then would *using* be an adjective?

*using the new steam presses* is an adverbial phrase describing how the book was printed.

That clause is fine.